# C++ How to pass a vector of pointers (double pointers) as a constant to a function

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a class `A` in C++ with many attributes:

```
 class A{
   public:
      B** tab;// B is another class or structure
      ....
      void compute();//this function does calculations on elements inside tab
   };
```

In a third class `C`, there is a function that uses the `tab` variable as input, reads each element and does some calculations to write results on another attribute of the class `C`:

```
C::compute(B** tab){
     ....// I need that **tab be protected inside this function and its elements does not change
 }
```

How can I make `tab`: the vector of pointers protected (or constant) ?

Comment: why do you pass tab a pointer to pointer? Why do you keep a member of that type??

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is something like this:

```
C::compute(B * const * tab){
   // nothing in this array of pointers will be changed
   tab[0] = (B *) 0x3254; // compile error as desired
}
```

Or you can ban changing even pointer to pointers like this:

```
C::compute(B * const * const tab){
   // nothing in this array of pointers will be changed
   tab = (B * const *) 0x3254; // compile error
}
```

If you need to protect only pointers in array the first example is your choice

Comment: Full protection is `C::compute(B const * const * tab) { ...`, With `C::compute(B * const * const tab)`, the last `const` applies to `tab` as a local variable inside the function, preventing `tab = 0;`, which would have no effect on the caller's pointer or its data anyway.  Also this declaration still allows changes to the caller's data, like `tab[0][0] = B{};`.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `vector`:

```
class A {
    vector<vector<B> > tab;
    //...
}

C::compute(const vector<vector<B> >& tab) {
    // tab, tab[0] and tab[0][0] are all const
}
```

Comment: But what is the difference between:  **C::compute(const vector<vector<B> >& tab)** and  **C::compute(B * const * tab)**

Comment: @Cecile the first is a const reference to a vector of vector of B objects. It at most times is valid. The second is a pointer to a const array whose element is a pointer to B.